# Priority Queue Linked List Iterator NPE

Tags: java

Just like the title says, I am getting a null pointer exception whenever I try to call the iterator from my driver. The error points to this specific location in my class:

```
 public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new IteratorHelper();
}

    class IteratorHelper implements Iterator<E> {
    private int iteratorIndex;
    private long modCheck;
    Node<E> current;

    public IteratorHelper() {

        iteratorIndex = 0;
        modCheck = sequenceNumber;
        current = head;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (modCheck != sequenceNumber)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        return iteratorIndex < currentSize;
    }

    public E next() {
        if (!hasNext() && current != null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        iteratorIndex++;
        current = current.next;
        return current.data; //NPE <<<<<<<<<<
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

}

Why am I getting a NPE?

Comment: what is current initialized to? What if you have last node as current pointing to null, what do you think current.data would return then?

Comment: Short answer: because something is `null`. Please refer to the linked question.

Comment: We need to see more of the code, if the class is not initialized properly the you wouldnt be able to even call #next() without the NPE....

Comment: Probably `current` is null. try with `if (current == null || !hasNext())`

Comment: The error points to *what* specific location in your class?

Comment: I updated the question with the whole iterator.